# Pdf export in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I need to export an HTML page with some charts in to a PDF, what are some good gems to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFKit http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit and Prawn http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn.

My choice is PDFKit.

In deal with charts it can be a problem. Recommend to use graphic charts in this case. But maybe canvas is supported.

Comment: Prawn doesn't take html as input, it only provides Ruby API. (not sure about PDFKit)

Comment: PDFKit  uses webkit for rendering, so it is good choise. Prawn is really don't approach

Answer (score 4):

I use [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to export the ouputted HTML of pages from Ruby on Rails as PDF. It works very well, and supports a ton of options.

I'm leaving this as a breadcrumb for anyone who comes across this question later...

Answer (score 3):

I just tackled a project involving complex tables, graphs pulled from Google charts and looked at three options:

- prawn
- pdfkit
- wickedpdf

Prawn is brilliantly done but its the right choice for making a simple invoice not a complex set of data which needs to exist both in html from Ruby views and PDF.

pdfkit and wickedpdf are both pdf renderers from html templates and they use the same underlying engine.  This is being done for an older Rails 2.3 app and I was able to get pdfkit to work in development mode but not in production under Passenger.

I was unable to get wickedpdf to work at all in Rails 2.3.

Overall both of these look good but I had better luck with pdfkit for my application.  I would have spent at least a full week using Prawn and I got pdfkit working in less than a few hours.

Comment: iam using rails 2.3. and used prawn before. constructing with prawn to hard work, and it has lots of bugs, doesnt support so many things(its for so simple documents).
then i have switched to wicked_pdf. it to fast and much perfect than prawn. with less work.

Comment: Any chance you could explain how you were able to get the Google charts to render? I've been struggling with getting my line chart to render but my pie chart works for some reason...

Comment: Do any of these gems support a variable page height option? Basically, I want to make a PDF that is 11" x n".