# HTML page to PDF converter in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there available any gem or plugins to convert HTML page to PDF?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Convert HTML to PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357212/rails-convert-html-to-pdf)

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357212/rails-convert-html-to-pdf

Comment: Hi @Jakub, @kurumi. It's not a duplicate post. I don't need to convert HTML to PDF. I want entire HTML page to PDF. i.e i will give the URL and it should convert the PDF page.

Comment: @Mr. Black I fail to see a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pdf export in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085424/pdf-export-in-rails)

Comment: @Jakub Hampl, @kurumi it is quite out of date link

Comment: Off-topic on SO, but on-topic in softwarerecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45903/1834

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is and it is called pdfkit.  This is how I use it to convert markdown files for a book proposal to pdf:

```
require 'kramdown'
require 'pdfkit'

source = ARGV[0] || 'proposal.md'
output = source.sub(/\.md$/, '.pdf')

home = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..')

markdown = File.read(File.join(home, 'src', source))

html = Kramdown::Document.new(markdown).to_html

kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')

kit.to_file(File.join(home, 'doc', output))

fork do
  system("open #{File.join(home, 'doc', output)}")
end
```

Comment: Just pass url to PDFKit - that's all.

Answer (score 12):

PDFKit: https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdfkit'
kit = PDFKit.new("http://my_web_site.com")
kit.to_file("my_web_site.pdf")
```

Also, good screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit

Comment: Always nice when people actually answer valuable SE questions instead of just downvoting or closing them.